# How to find "last modified time" of a folder in java

Tags: java, timestamp, file-handling

I want to continuously monitor a folder (say C:/Users/me/csv) for any change in its content -

1. either new files added, or (sub-folder changes doesn't bother me as of now)
2. existing file modified

If either of two happens, what is 'the parameter of csv folder' which gets modified? (anything like `timestamp` which I can compare with previous value of that parameter and trigger loading the csv data again to my collection)

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was the reason WatchService was added to JDK 7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Good resource. I don't even knew what to look for. I'll read and see if it fulfills my need.

Comment: I found a better resource helpful in this context :
http://www.javabeat.net/watchservice-api-java7-monitor-directory/